# How do I uninstall Macports from OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macports, ncurses

I installed Macports on OS X Mavericks and then I switched to Homebrew. Now I upgraded to OS X Yosemite and suddenly remembered to uninstall macports so that home-brew doesn't have any build problems. But when I try to uninstall I get a platform mismatch error which is obvious as I upgraded my OS X. As I am very new at this, can anyone help with step by step instructions to completely remove macports from system.

Comment: This is not a programming question so probably off topic on SO. It is better suited to [Superuser](http://superuser.com/) or even better [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/), both StackExchange sites more appropriate for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo port -v -f uninstall active` will not work while you haven't upgraded your MacPorts installation. You can use the MacPorts installer for Yosemite from the website to get a working MacPorts again. Once you did that, follow [the official uninstall instructions](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did that, first downloaded the Macports package for yosemite and installed that. then used the macports uninstallation guide to remove it. It worked perfectly with no troubles. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do (assuming you used /opt/local):

```
sudo port -v -f uninstall active
sudo rm -rf /opt/local
```